# Javascript - using foreach doesn´t generate the correct output from my database - MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on a project in mvc and I have in my view a `foreach` to create several `<li>` elements with information which comes from my database.

In my script like you see in my code I have add a variable to my id to have a unique id for each one.

At the end what I do with my counter is to add +1.

My problem is that only the last `<li>` element shows the icon which are in my script.

What can I do it to show for all `<li>` elements the complete data?

Thanks in advance:

**Here is my code:**

```
    @{int x = 0;}
<ul>
    @foreach (var p in ViewBag.MyIcon)
    {        
        <script>
            //window.onload = function() {  
            var a = new R(document.getElementById('@("inner" + x.ToString())', 75, 75));
            var b = paper.path("@p.Icon");
            tetronimo.attr({ fill: 'rgb(53,106,160)', stroke: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)', 'stroke-width': 0 });
            //}  
        </script>

        <li>
            <div id="@("inner" + x.ToString())">
                <div class="text">
                    @p.Name
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        x = x + 1;
    }
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you should insert your `<script>` snippet after the `<div id='innerX'>`, maybe inside the `<li>` to have a valid html, to make sure the item is yet in the page when you call **document.getElementById('innerX')**.

Comment: i have the ul element in my project... i haven´t put it here because i thought it not necessary

Comment: Please write what should be the expected html

Comment: i have set the script into the div inner